# Send POST request using CURL command and retrieve using PHP

Tags: php, linux, curl

I'm trying to HTTP POST using the following command on linux

curl -X POST --data-ascii "a=hello world" http://www.mysite.com/controller/function_name

Its not working, my server is not accepting the POST at all.

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

whereas if I try this on my local machine it works.

For ex.
curl -X POST --data-ascii "a=hello world" http://192.168.1.10/controller/function_name

Also, the server is shared host, is it a problem?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear: are you are running both curl commands on your local machine, but the one that calls the php page on your server fails?

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])` in your script. Maybe there's a redirect of some sort occurring, causing your POST to be turned into a GET, over which the post data will NOT be propagated.

Comment: @AndrewR - yes, I'm trying both commands from local machine, but server command fails - actually it is not printing anything. Tried different methods.

Comment: If you put this in an HTML file, open it in a browser, and click the button, does it show anything? `<html><body><form action="http://www.mysite.com/controller/function_name" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="a" value="hello world"><input type="submit" value="Go"></form></body></html>`

Comment: yes, it gives - Array ( [a] => hello world )

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working"? do you still get an http 200 response? 0? 500? run nslookup www.mysite.com, does a normal page without php code work when you curl it? use var_dump instead of print_r, your shared host may have errors supressed, you can try enabling error reporting in your script